# Worker nodes not available

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I have setup and installed IBM Cloud private CE with two ubuntu images in Virtual Box.  I can ssh into both images and from there ssh into the others.  The ICp dashboard shows only one active node I was expecting two.

I explicitly ran the command (from a root user on master node):

```
docker run -e LICENSE=accept --net=host \
  -v "$(pwd)":/installer/cluster \
  ibmcom/cfc-installer install -l \
  192.168.27.101
```

The result of this command seemed to be a successful addition of the worker node:

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.27.101             : ok=45   changed=11   unreachable=0    failed=0
```

But still the worker node isn't showing in the dashboard.

What should I be checking to ensure the worker node will work for the master node?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Vagrant to configure IBM Cloud Private, I'd highly recommend trying https://github.com/IBM/deploy-ibm-cloud-private

The project will use a `Vagrantfile` to configure a master/proxy and then provision 2 workers *within the image* using LXD. You'll get better density and performance on your laptop with this configuration over running two full Virtual Box images (1 for master/proxy, 1 for the worker).

Answer (score 0):

You can check on your worker node with following steps:

1. check cluster nodes status
   `kubectl get nodes` to check status of the newly added worker node
2. if it's `NotReady`, check kubelet log if there is error message about why kubelet is not running properly:

   - ICp 2.1
     `systemctl status kubelet`
   - ICp 1.2
     `docker ps -a|grep kubelet` to get kubelet_containerid, 
     `docker logs kubelet_containerid`

Comment: Thanks @rebecca-guo.  I ran the command (ICp 2.1beta) and all seems well.

kubelet.service - Kubelet Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2017-09-14 18:11:20 UTC; 50min ago
     Docs: ...
 Main PID: 1173 (hyperkube)
    Tasks: 21
   Memory: 145.8M
      CPU: 3min 788ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           ├─1173 /opt/kubernetes/hyperkube kubelet --feature-gates Accelerators=true --allow-privileged=true --docker-disable-shared-p
           └─1603 journalctl -k -f

Comment: what did you get if you run `docker ps -a` on your worker nodes, can you see any exited containers, if yes, can you enter into the containers see if there is any error messages?

Comment: Thanks for the tip Rebecca!  After playing a little bit I notice this one container (ibmcom/calico-node) keeps exiting.  The logs say:

time="2017-09-14T21:39:35Z" level=info msg="NODENAME environment not specified - check HOSTNAME"

and 

Calico node 'icpworker1' is already using the IPv4 address 10.0.3.15:

Comment: if the `icpworker1` is your new worker node try to add in, can you please check in your /etc/hosts file if there is `127.0.1.1 localhost` in it, please remove it

Comment: Thanks Rebecca.  I think there was a 127.0.0.1 mapping in there.  Removed it and all is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Run this to get the kubectl working

```
ln -sf /opt/kubernetes/hyperkube /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

run the below command to identified failed pods if any in the setup on the master node.

Run this to get the pods details running in the environment
kubectl -n kube-system get pods -o wide

for restarting any failed pods of icp

```
txt="0/";ns="kube-system";type="pods"; kubectl -n $ns get $type | grep "$txt" | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs kubectl -n $ns delete $type
```

now run the kubectl cluster-info

kubectl get nodes

Then ckeck the cluster info command of kubectl

```
Check kubectl version is giving you https://localhost:8080  or https://masternodeip:8001
```

kubectl cluster-info

Do you get the output

if no.. 
then

```
login to https://masternodeip:8443 using admin login
```

and then copy the configure clientcli settings by clicking on admin on the panel 
paste it in ur master node.

and run the 
kubectl cluster-info